# MassTransit configured with StructureMap - ContainerScoped not working

Tags: structuremap, masstransit

I've configured a class X with ContainerScope in my StructureMap configuration, but for some reason, when the app initially starts up and MassTransit consumer consumes the initial message, it creates the instance, but on subsequent messages received for that consumer, the consumer is recreated, but not object X (I would expect a new instance is created per message received). I know if I configure it with transient it'll work, but I just want a single instance of that class created for the entirety of the processing of that message.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see some code of how you are configuring your consumers? What version of MassTransit are you using?

Answer (score 1):

When using MassTransit, creating a new consumer instance is the preferred behavior for each message. It is recommended that any state or behavior that needs to be maintained as a single instance across messages is done using a dependency of that consumer (which can be configured in the container by the application developer).

> I realize that you are asking how to configure your consumer to be a singleton, and you can probably figure that out, but MassTransit will reconfigure the container to make it scoped for each message if you're using AddMassTransit/AddConsumer.

A better approach is to have your state configured:

```
public interface IConsumerState
{
}

public class ConsumerState :
    IConsumerState
{
}

x.For<IConsumerState>().Use<ConsumerState>().Singleton();
```

Then, for MassTransit, configure your consumer where your consumer depends upon that interface.

```
public class Consumer :
    IConsume<Message>
{
    public Consumer(IConsumerState state)
    {
        _state = state;
    }

    public async Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
    {
    }
}

x.AddMassTransit(m =>
{
    m.AddConsumer<Consumer>();
    m.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints();
    }
});
```

Using this approach, a new consumer is created for each message and the state is maintained/shared by all consumer instances.

Comment: Hey Chris. I looked into what you had mentioned. I'm not after a singleton across all mesages, but rather a "per request" instance, e.g. an EF DbContext across the lifetime of the processing of a message.

As I'm following the documentation @ https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/structuremap.html#using-a-registry, and as I'm using a registry, I've followed the "Using a Registry" section. I'm unable to use the 
"x.ReceiveEndpoint("customer_update_queue", e => e.LoadFrom(context));"
code as it complains that LoadFrom is obsolete.

Comment: It is, you should be using `.ConfigureConsumer()` or `ConfigureConsumers()` within the `ReceiveEndpoint("name", ec => ...)` method. Or `ConfigureSaga(s)`, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not getting something that's probably clearly obvious. I tired changing from "e.Consumer(consumerType,_container.GetInstance)" to "e.ConfigureConsumer(_container,consumerTypes)" but now failing with "StructureMapConfigurationException:No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'MassTransit.IRegistration'", which from your reply to the post https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1322 is registered on using AddMasstransit, which isn't what I'm using due to following the "Using a Registry" section as mentioned in previous reply.

Comment: Oh, right. There is an .AddConsumersFromContainer() method for StructureMap, I think. I'll look at rewrite the registry documentation to make it so that once all the modules are loaded the bus can be configured with AddMassTransit.